# Making a gameObject push the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am working on a Unity 3D game for Oculus and I have problems with making my objects to apply physics on a player. So getting rid of a CharacterController and using something like a rag doll is not an option.

I am using OVRPlayerController, that has a Rigidbody with mass 1 and a box collider on it. My gameObject has a Rigidbody of mass 100, and a box collider. But when the object hits the player it just goes through it, whereas I want it to push the player in x direction.

I tried using onColliderHit but it doesn't even recognize the collision between the player and the object, so I checked box collider on the object to be a trigger and I use OnTriggerEnter() to recognize the collision.

I tried to translate the player's position on collision, but player gets positioned to weird places out of my map for some reason. Here is what I use:

```
info.transform.Translate(new Vector3( -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
info.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

I also tried to manually set the x position of the player but this doesn't work, and I know I am not supposed to do it.

I searched for answers for a long long time, so please don't answer to this with something like "oh, have you tried googling it, there are a lot of similar questions" etc.

Answer (score 1):

It should be detecting the collision just fine, as long as one of the box colliders has a non-kinematic (Is Kinematic = false) rigidbody attached.

Make sure Is Trigger is false, and you specified a material for your collider.

Also try messing with the other properties on the rigidbody, such as Collision Detection and Mass. The unity docs indicate that your mass should be no more or less than 100 times that of other rigidbodies.

Comment: Ok I fixed that but no when my wall is colliding with the player, it just stops. I locked rotation of the wall so it doesnt flip over the player like it used to before I locked rotation. But now it stops when hitting a player AND a player can push it. I can run into it and it just flies to the end of the corridor and keeps coming towards again because I use lerp. Its actually pretty funny, its like a battle with the wall. But its not what i want...

Comment: It sounds like you need to mess with the properties of your wall material? Are you using a physics material? Usually when it just stops, that means the friction is too high or the bounciness is too low

Comment: I dont use any material on my box collider... I just have a texture on my shader?.....

Comment: Its says (None) Physics Material

Comment: I am just not sure how adding a material will fix the fact that the player can supercharge the wall so it bounces all the way back to the end of the corridor....